# Installer package for program that uses JDBC to connect to MySQL

Tags: jdbc

I have an installer wizard thing called 'install creator'. I want to include my mySQL database into the installer or find another way that the user, upon installation, can just use my database. Prob is-not everyone has MySQL installed on the computer and even then, the user doesn't know the name of the database or my password. Somehow the database must be created automatically upon install, and for my purposes, some of the tables created. How can one do this. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I'm using JDBC to interact with the database....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using MySQL as a local storage engine, as it seems to be what you are doing, then you should consider using [Sqlite with JDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/), instead of MySQL. MySQL is really intended to be used on a server, where information from multiple users is stored, and where the database is accessed only indirectly through the programs that you create that run on the server. You could, in theory, package up MySQL and MySQL Connector/J which lets JDBC talk with MySQL; however, MySQL is a pretty big beast, and I don't think it's nice to do that to your users (also, don't forget that they might already have MySQL installed, and if you were to install MySQL for the first time, you would effectively be forcing them to use your root password). Unlike MySQL, sqlite is intended to provide the structure of SQL for use with lightweight, local file storage.